# How can I track a Python package usage?

Tags: python, jupyter

I've developed a python package and deployed to a Jupyter server so that everyone from our company who has access to the Jupyter server can use it.

My question is how I can get some usage stats of this package, things like how many unique users have used(imported) this package? How many times has this package been used?

Comment: unless you add your own telemetry, there is no way

Comment: By any chance, did you got a workaround for this? I have similar use case and look for options to accomplish it.